# Remove MS Office 2016 activate window

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Have no idea why I'm always getting window below during any Office application startup. My Office 2016 is activated and I can work with it without problem. How to remove this window?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remove MS Office 2016 activation prompt when it's activated already**

Two solutions below plus other resources and references:

> ### [Repeated Activation Prompts occur after installing Volume License version of 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3170450/repeated-activation-prompts-occur-after-installing-volume-license-version-of-2016)
>
> [322756](https://support.microsoft.com/help/322756) How to back up and
>   restore the registry in Windows
>
> To resolve this problem, export the following registry keys and delete
>   from computer.
>
> 1. Close activation screen.
> 2. On the **Start** menu, click **Run**.
> 3. Type **regedit**, and then press **Enter**.
> 4. Select the following key in the registry.
>
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\OEM`
> 5. Right click the **OEM** value and click **File>Export**.
> 6. Save the key
> 7. Once the key is backed-up, click on **Edit>Delete**
> 8. Repeat steps 4-7 with following key
>
>    `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Common\OEM`
>
> Exit Registry Editor
>
> <sub>[source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3170450/repeated-activation-prompts-occur-after-installing-volume-license-version-of-2016)</sub>

---

> I did confirm that after again uninstalling the activated Office,
>   again checking for a "Get Office" icon to uninstall, and then running
>   the online Microsoft automated uninstaller at
>   https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US
>   that the next re-install of Office seems to run successfully.
>
> <sub>[source](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d53fc6aa-ee6f-41d3-9e97-0ec72f9387ec/office-2016-activation-dialog-appears-every-time-an-office-app-starts?forum=officeitpro)</sub>

---

### Further Resources

- [Office 2016 Activation dialog appears every time an Office app starts](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d53fc6aa-ee6f-41d3-9e97-0ec72f9387ec/office-2016-activation-dialog-appears-every-time-an-office-app-starts?forum=officeitpro)
- [Repeated Activation Prompts occur after installing Volume License version of 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3170450/repeated-activation-prompts-occur-after-installing-volume-license-version-of-2016)
- [Microsoft automated uninstaller](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Uninstall-Office-2016-Office-2013-or-Office-365-from-a-PC-9dd49b83-264a-477a-8fcc-2fdf5dbf61d8?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

Comment: found other solutions here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d53fc6aa-ee6f-41d3-9e97-0ec72f9387ec/office-2016-activation-dialog-appears-every-time-an-office-app-starts?forum=officeitpro&prof=required One solution worked for many people, search for UncHellMatt, the solution is about running a command: cscript "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office16\OSPP.VBS" /unpkey:xxxxx